# Changing Pivot Table source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have problem with following code:

```
Sub sChangePivotRange()

Dim lngLastRow as Long
Dim rngPivotRange as Range
Dim strPivotRange as String

lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rngPivotRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:AC" & lngLastRow)

strPivotRange = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & rngPivotRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RANKING").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\[Ranks.xlsb]Ranks!R5C3:R117708C29" _
        , Version:=6)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RANKING").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        strPivotRange _
        , Version:=6)

End Sub
```

This part works flawlessly:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RANKING").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
            Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "C:\[Ranks.xlsb]Ranks!R5C3:R117708C29" _
            , Version:=6)
```

While this part results with an error:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RANKING").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
            Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            strPivotRange _
            , Version:=6)
```

Error text is:

```
“The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.”
```

Obviously putting `?strPivotRange` in Immediate Window results with `C:\[Ranks.xlsb]Ranks!R5C3:R117708C29`.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Lukasz

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but aren't those caches overlapping? Like, if you perform just the second part of the code, you get the error anyways? Maybe it's the execution of both of them in a row what is causing the error.

Comment: When I execute only second part there's an error too... I showed both parts just for comparison purposes. First part is what I have recorded while changing pivot source manually. I want to use second part because pivot source is changing after each refresh of whole report.

Comment: Are all columns named? According to this link https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottableerrors.html, this raises this error (though if the first piece of code works I guess it is correct).
I can't think of any error so my advice would be to simply the code (avoid using "_") and try to really compare those strings, maybe there is some different not seen in the console print... If not, explore if there is any "workaround" to make the same changes with other functions. Sorry and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround (I recalled that I already did such thing few years ago):

First, I added a name for the range that will be the pivot table source:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="PIVOT_SOURCE", RefersToR1C1:="=Ranks!R5C3:R" & lngLastRow & "C29"
```

Then I used this name as a source for the pivot table:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RANKING").ChangePivotCache _
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="PIVOT_SOURCE", Version:=6)
```

Hope that helps someone else in the future.

Lukasz